# SDL microservice taxonomies.GetTaxonomyKeywords(uri) is not returning metadata

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion, taxonomy, microservices

I am using below code to retrieve the taxonomy in microservices, but I am not getting the metadata

```
   var taxonomies = new TaxonomyFactory();
   var root = taxonomies.GetTaxonomyKeywords(uri);
```

am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you using the uri of a category, is it correct for the publication and have you published the category?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "I am not getting the metadata"?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in SDL Web 8.1.1. It has been resolved in later versions and will be available in the next on-premise release too.

Comment: ok.. thank you :-)

Comment: Any idea if this has been fixed ??

Comment: I ran into same issue. I am on 8.1.1. There is hotfix CD_8.2.0.2810 that addresses this issue. All CIL+services above 8.2.2 have this fix in also.

Answer (score 2):

You can find examples of how to use the CD Taxonomy API here:
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Navigation/DynamicNavigationProvider.cs

(Search for `GetTaxonomyKeywords`)

Comment: I have a taxonomy list that contains list of keywords with metadata. when I query for single keyword instead of taxonomy, the function returning keywords with metadata information.

I am using the same method in non web-8 version and I am getting the keyword with metadata.

I referred the sample you have mentioned above, but no luck

Comment: did u meant this one:https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Query/BrokerQuery.cs